# Reading c parameters in assembly

Tags: assembly, i386

I want to access the parameters of this function in an assembly program called compute.

```
extern void compute(void *a, void *b, char *operation)
    asm("compute");
```

Both a and b are signed numbers that can be bigger than 32 bits.

Does this have something to do with the stack?
Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: I believe there are other similar questions like this that can help you (not sure though). You have to tag the architecture precisely and something that can tell use the ABI, like the OS and the compiler flags.

Comment: Use GNU C Extended syntax, not basic, so you can use input/output operands.  See the [inline assembly tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info)

Comment: @lurker: **no no no, do NOT write *inline* asm that makes assumptions about where C variable are in registers or memory**.  Don't even suggest that GNU C basic asm syntax is usable for this.  Your code will break as soon as it inlines into another function (e.g. when you compile with `-O3`).  If you want to do stuff like that, write your whole function in asm and call it from C (with a prototype).  Doing that from inline asm defeats the entire purpose of it, which is that the compiler can optimize around a small fragment of asm without the overhead of a function call.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did not intend to offer such advice and didn't spell it out that way. But I deleted my comment to avoid any potential confusion in that regard.

Comment: @lurker: ok good :)  Because it sounded like you were suggesting looking at `gcc -S` output to see where stuff was, and then writing inline-asm that looked for it there.  That of course can break with a different compiler, options, or surrounding code.  And just leaving EAX set at the end of an inline-asm statement isn't the same thing as returning a value...  I was having a hard time explaining this to someone else [doing the same thing recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821084/powerpc-why-is-this-returning-177-adding-parameters-together?noredirect=1#comment68871097_40821084)

Comment: @ireally: before using inline asm, read the warning label: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.  Like I said, write whole functions in plain (not inline) asm.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to docs about calling conventions and so on.  And look at compiler output to see what it's doing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm "not allowed" to modify the c function.

Comment: Ok wait a minute, I was reading it as `int compute(args) { asm("compute"); }` (A function definition containing an inline-asm statement.)  But that's not what you wrote; there are no braces, so it's not a function definition.    (@lurker, this is what I thought the question was when I quickly skimmed your comment about looking at `gcc -S` output and over-reacted.  Oops!)  There's no semi-colon either, so it's not valid syntax.  Can you make it clearer what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: ... And what is the string inside the asm() statement?  Is `"compute"` a placeholder for the implementation you're going to write?  Are you supposed to write a stand-alone function definition inside an asm statement at global scope?